# CLion & SDL WinMain@16 error

Tags: c++, cmake, sdl

I have an issue. I keep getting a WinMain@16 error when trying to use the library SDL 1.2. (I understand it's outdated, but I have a use for it for the time being). Everything compiles just fine when I unlink the library in CLion using the CMakeList.txt

I also have read somewhere I need to add the following flags, -lmingw32 -lSDLmain -lSDL -mwindows, yet I don't know where to add them to. When adding them to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS I get an error where Windows cant find it.

Here's my code.

CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(test2)

set(SDL_PATH "C:/SDK/SDL-1.2")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

find_package(SDL REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(test2 ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(test2 ${SDL_LIBRARY})
```

I also have the built in cache linked to

SDL_LIBRARY = SDL-1.2/lib

SDL_INCLUDE_DIR = SDL-1.2/include

SDLMAIN_LIBRARY SDL-1.2/lib/libSDLmain.a

My C++ Code atm

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    SDL_Rect test = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try ```add_executable(test2 WIN32 ${SOURCE_FILES})```

Comment: Doesn't appear to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Make sure your main method is of the form:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

}
```

Note the added parameters

2) You link your static libraries using `target_link_libraries(target lib)`

So you have to link like this:

```
target_link_libraries(test2 SDL SDLmain)
```

You can download the **prebuilt development libraries** from here.

https://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php

Comment: That got me to a new area, the issue I have now is that it can't find -lSDL and -lSDLmain